# n1ql query where clause return all if arguement is empty or null

Tags: couchbase, sql++

How to write an n1ql query to return records if the argument passed in where clause is empty or null?

```
[{
 "name": "John",
 "age": 12
},
{
 "name": "Smith",
 "age": 12
},
{
 "name": "Kevin",
 "age": 15
}]
```

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM #{#n1ql.bucket} " +
            "WHERE age = $1;")
List<Name> findByAge(Integer age);
```

Expected:
**If age is empty** 
return

```
[{
 "name": "John",
 "age": 12
},
{
 "name": "Smith",
 "age": 12
},
{
 "name": "Kevin",
 "age": 15
}]
```

**If age is 12**
return

```
[{
 "name": "John",
 "age": 12
},
{
 "name": "Smith",
 "age": 12
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM default
WHERE age = $1 OR IFMISSINGORNULL($1,"") = "";
```

Comment: How i can add multiple conditions to this?